# css border - запретить влиять на позицию элемента

Tags: css3, position, border

Как заставить увеличение границы не влиять на позицию абсолютного элемента?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:focus::before {
border: solid 4px rgba(255, 216, 64, 0.6);
content:'cxcx';
}
input:checked:active + .slider {
   background-color: #303030;
   border: solid 10px #ffc620;
   position: absolute;
  }
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:active + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  border: solid 4px rgba(255, 216, 64, .6);
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.slider:focus {
}



input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  border: solid 4px rgba(255, 216, 64, .6);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: У тя там столько лишнего... Я бы больше половины стилей удалил...

Comment: box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 216, 64, 0.6);

Comment: но, box-shadow - это обход проблемы. ответа так и нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не стоит использовать псевдо-классы или псевдо-элементы там где они в принципе не нужны.

Я бы реализовал так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#label-wrap {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

label.switch {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #2196F3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

label.switch:active~.slider {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: green;
}

input:checked~.slider {
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 27px;
}

input:checked~label.switch {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="label-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inp">
    <label class="switch" for="inp"></label>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. но как добавить border и background-color на него, при :focus на ползунке?

Comment: чего то я поспешил...  Как понять при `focus`, объясни что именно хочешь реализовать?

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял....  Но ответ изменил...

Comment: событие :focus. наводится мышка на кругляшик слайдера - он светиться желтым border. 
событие :active - я так понимаю, зажимается мышка на кругляшике - меняется фон за ним овала.

Comment: border должен появляться снаружи кругляшика, а не внутри. - в этом и вопрос, и вся сложность.

Comment: box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 216, 64, 0.6); - все, вот решение! спасиБо за помощь!

Comment: Ну тогда не бордер а тень...  ок

Comment: @Air хороший ответ, возьму на заметку

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я бы это реализовал на `JS`...  Это крайний вариант на `css` для меня